# merge repetitive specific record and keep some value of the removed ones in R

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have a huge dataset which contains four column of `user_id`, `action`, `start_time` and `end_time`. I want to merge consecutive of action `"o"` and `start_time` would the first `start_time` and `end_time` is `end_time` of the last merged record.
let's say `df`:

```
"user_id","action","start_time","end_time"
"11","o",23:25:27,23:25:49
"11","o",23:25:28,23:25:28
"11","o",23:25:48,23:26:50
"11","v",23:25:49,23:25:49
"11","v",23:25:49,23:25:50
"11","o",23:28:24,00:22:33
"11","o",00:10:48,00:23:44
"22","o",00:11:52,00:22:33
"22","o",00:22:32,00:27:44
"22","v",00:22:42,00:22:42
"22","o",00:22:42,00:22:42
"22","z",00:22:42,00:22:43
```

I want to merge rownumber 1, 2 and 3 because both have action `"o"` and the merger have `start_time` of the first row and `end_time` of the second. the same applied to row number `6` and `7` as well as rownumber `8` and `9`.
So the desired output:

```
    "user_id","action","start_time","end_time"
    "11","o",23:25:27,23:26:50
    "11","v",23:25:49,23:25:49
    "11","v",23:25:49,23:25:50
    "11","o",23:28:24,00:23:44
    "22","o",00:11:52,00:27:44
    "22","v",00:22:42,00:22:42
    "22","o",00:22:42,00:22:42
    "22","z",00:22:42,00:22:43
```

How can I do it in R?
thx

Comment: I think there's an error in your desired output. Rows 4 and 5 of your input should be merged together, so the sequence of `action` values in your desired output should be: `o, v, o, o, v, o, z`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind a `data.table` solution,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, {
    if (action[1L]=="o") {
        .(start_time=start_time[1L], end_time=end_time[.N])
    } else {
        .(start_time, end_time)
    }
}, by=.(rleid(action), user_id, action)][, -1L]

#   user_id action start_time end_time
#1:      11      o   23:25:27 23:26:50
#2:      11      v   23:25:49 23:25:49
#3:      11      v   23:25:49 23:25:50
#4:      11      o   23:28:24 00:23:44
#5:      22      o   00:11:52 00:27:44
#6:      22      v   00:22:42 00:22:42
#7:      22      o   00:22:42 00:22:42
#8:      22      z   00:22:42 00:22:43
```

data:

```
df <- read.csv(text='"user_id","action","start_time","end_time"
"11","o",23:25:27,23:25:49
"11","o",23:25:28,23:25:28
"11","o",23:25:48,23:26:50
"11","v",23:25:49,23:25:49
"11","v",23:25:49,23:25:50
"11","o",23:28:24,00:22:33
"11","o",00:10:48,00:23:44
"22","o",00:11:52,00:22:33
"22","o",00:22:32,00:27:44
"22","v",00:22:42,00:22:42
"22","o",00:22:42,00:22:42
"22","z",00:22:42,00:22:43')
```

Answer (score 0):

A 99% tidyverse solution with thanks to @jasbner for suggesting `data.table::rleid`:

Using `data.table::rleid`, we can give each sequential group a unique id. Then it's just a simple matter of grouping by `rlid` and then using `summarize` to find the earliest `start_time` and latest `end_time`. By default, summarize drops all other variables, so you have to explicitly preserve them as below. Finally we drop the `rlid` variable so it matches your example, but that might be good to keep for the future.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df  %>% 
    mutate(rlid = data.table::rleid(user_id,action)) %>% 
    group_by(rlid) %>%
    summarize(user_id = user_id[1],
              action = action[1],
              start_time = min(start_time),
              end_time = max(end_time)) %>%
    select(-rlid)

  user_id action start_time end_time
    <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>   
1      11 o      23:25:27   23:26:50
2      11 v      23:25:49   23:25:50
3      11 o      00:10:48   00:23:44
4      22 o      00:11:52   00:27:44
5      22 v      00:22:42   00:22:42
6      22 o      00:22:42   00:22:42
7      22 z      00:22:42   00:22:43
```

This method will collapse any number of repeated rows and is (I think) much simpler to understand than a pure `data.table` method.

Answer (score 0):

My process: First we add a run length encoding id with `rleid` this will allow us to consider the actions as separate groups.  Next we add two temporary columns `st` and `et` that signify the start and end time of each group.  Then, we `filter` and get all actions not "o" or if it is "o" we take the first one.  Then in groups where the action is "o" we want to replace the start and end time by the temporary columns.  Last we `select` only the columns you want for the final table.

This should work for multiple length runs of "o" action.  I'm sure there is a better way to do the last mutate but I wanted to put this out there.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
  mutate(rlid = rleid(user_id,action)) %>% 
  group_by(rlid) %>% 
  mutate(st = start_time[row_number()==1], et = end_time[row_number = n()]) %>%
  filter(action!="o" | row_number()==1) %>% 
  mutate(start_time = case_when(action=="o"~st,
                                action!="o"~start_time),
         end_time = case_when(action=="o"~et,
                              action!="o"~end_time)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(user_id:end_time)

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   user_id action start_time end_time
#     <int> <fct>  <fct>      <fct>   
# 1      11 o      23:25:27   23:26:50
# 2      11 v      23:25:49   23:25:49
# 3      11 v      23:25:49   23:25:50
# 4      11 o      23:28:24   00:23:44
# 5      22 o      00:11:52   00:27:44
# 6      22 v      00:22:42   00:22:42
# 7      22 o      00:22:42   00:22:42
# 8      22 z      00:22:42   00:22:43
```

Comment: thank you, but when I run in my data, `end_time` is completely wrong. seems that it generates random datetime !